# How to retrieve data from the selected row?

Tags: winforms, listview, textbox

I have a List-View named lvList, two textboxes named txtNumber and txtName respectively.

*Properties of LIstView (that I have
 changed):*

> FullRowSelect = True
>
> MultiSelect = False

When I select a row, I want the respective Number and Item-Name to be displayed in the below text-boxes. How can I achieve this ?

[image]

Working in VS-2010 (Winforms)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
foreach ( ListViewItem item in lvList.SelectedItems)
{
    number = item.SubItems[0].Text;
    name = item.SubItems[1].Text;
}
```

Or in your case if you always have only one item selected:

```
String number,name;
ListViewItem item = lvList.SelectedItems[0];
if ( item != null)
{
    number = item.SubItems[0].Text;
    name = item.SubItems[1].Text;
}
```

**Update**:
I usually don't write code in VB but it should be something like:

```
Dim number as String
Dim name as String
Dim item as ListViewItem = lvList.SelectedItems[0]
if item != null then
    number = item.SubItems[0].Text
    name = item.SubItems[1].Text
end if
```

(i haven't compiled this so it could have errors)

Comment: Can you update the answer with Vb code , I am not good with C#

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have some sort of object that is in some sort of collection that is population the listviews datasource

For example purposes let us say your class looks as follows

```
public class YourClass()
{
    public Integer Number {get; set;}
    public String ItemName {get; set;}
}
```

In the `SelectedIndexChanged` Event Handler for your ListView

```
var selectedItem = lvList.SelectedItems[0];
txtNumber.Text = selectedItem.Number.ToString();
txtName.Text = selectedItem.ItemName.ToString();
```

Now if you are just assigning items to specific columns in the listview then let me know and I can show you how to do that instead.

Comment: Error: `'SelectedItem' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView'`.

Comment: @SpongeBob SquarePants, yea, that was suppose to be `lvList.SelectedItems[0]` wrong language crept in to my example.